# Qt: Lists of user defined objects

Tags: python, qt

I want to use Qt to provide a graphical interface to a collection of user defined objects. For example I may have the following python class

```
class Person(object):
    def __init__(self, name, age):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age
```

and a linked list of instances

```
people = [Person('John', 60), Person('Laura', 33)]
```

I now want to use Qt to present a browsable list of the elements in `people`. Perhaps I want to allow certain information to be displayed in various text boxes when the user clicks on the names of people in this list.

The Qt documentation contains the example of an [address book](http://doc.qt.digia.com/4.7/tutorials-addressbook.html) which is pretty good match to my own case, but there are two crucial things missing from this tutorial

1. In the address book tutorial the actual data (which in this case are the addresses of various persons) is stored in a QMap. Each name and address is represented as a QString. The QMap maps names to addresses. This is fine for that simple example, but I want to wrap a Qt interface around my *own* data. How is this done?
2. The address book does not show how to display a list of existing address book entries.

I think the notion of the model/view architecture is relevant to this so I have read the [model/view](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/model-view-programming.html) documentation. This documentation seems to strongly emphasize the use of Qt built-in container classes. This is fine but in the end I want to wrap this around my own data structures and I have not found a an explanation of how to do this.

QUESTIONS:

1. How do I write code to expose my own pre-existing data through a Qt list or other graphical interface?
2. The documentation on the model/view system is really confusing. How does Qt expect the data and associated viewable classes to be organized?

I am dedicated to understanding this and improving the documentation for others. If this thread attracts attention and useful information I will attempt to have it properly archived on the Qt webpage.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code does what I want. I used the Qt Designer to make a ui with the following elements

- firstNameLineEdit - QLineEdit: Enter a person's first name here.
- lastNameLineEdit - QLineEdit: Enter a person's last name here.
- addPersonButton - QPushButton: Press this button to add a new Person object. The first and last names are retrieved from the line edits.
- displayButton - QPushButton: prints a list of all existing Person instances to the console for debugging
- listView - QListView: A view to display the names of the Person objects

And now the code...

```
import PyQt4.QtCore as QtCore
import PyQt4.QtGui as QtGui
import PyQt4.uic as uic
import sys

class Person(object):
    def __init__(self, firstName, lastName):
        self.firstName = firstName
        self.lastName = lastName

class MyWidget(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, people):
        QtGui.QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        uic.loadUi('MyWidget.ui', self)
        self.people=people
        self.addPersonButton.clicked.connect(self.addPerson)
        self.displayButton.clicked.connect(self.display)

        self.model = simpleModel(self.people)
        self.listView.setModel(self.model)

        self.show()

    def display(self):
        for i,p in enumerate(self.people):
            print "Person %i: %s %s"%(i, p.firstName, p.lastName)

    def addPerson(self):
        firstName = str(self.firstNameLineEdit.text())
        lastName = str(self.lastNameLineEdit.text())
        p = Person(firstName, lastName)
        self.model.insertRow(p)

class simpleModel(QtCore.QAbstractListModel):
    def __init__(self, dataList, parent=None):
        super(simpleModel, self).__init__(parent)
        self.list = dataList

    def rowCount(self, parent=QtCore.QModelIndex()):
        return len(self.list)

    def insertRow(self, data, parent=QtCore.QModelIndex()):
        self.beginInsertRows(parent, self.rowCount(), self.rowCount())
        self.list.append(data)
        self.endInsertRows()

    def data(self, index, role):
        if role == QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole:
            person = self.list[index.row()]
            return QtCore.QVariant("%s %s"%(person.firstName,person.lastName))
        elif role == QtCore.Qt.UserRole:
            person = self.list[index.row()]
            return person
        return QtCore.QVariant()    

def main():
    people=[Person('John','Doe')]
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = MyWidget(people)
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 1):

I've never used Python, but I presume that the port preserves the basic way Qt does MVC.  In that case, I'm not sure there's much to improve on over Qt's documentation, particularly [here](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtcore/qabstractlistmodel.html#details) and in the `QListView` [documentation](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtwidgets/qlistview.html).  In Qt's MVC, you are free to use *whatever you want* as the underlying data structure which holds your data.  What you provide--this is the key--are basic functions (pure virtual in `QAbstractListModel`) which tell the QListView how to access and if needed, modify your data.  There is also a basic function `rowCount` you need to implement which is self explanatory.

When you have implemented these in a `QAbstractListModel` subclass, just use `QListView::setModel` to set the model for the `QListView`, and everything should just work.  Again what I've given you is in C++ but I expect you can translate it to Python-Qt fairly straightforwardly.

Comment: Thank you, this is useful. I think by working with QAbstractListModel I can figure it out. If I get something working I'll post the source here. If someone would write an example in C++ for the Qt pages that would also be really nice.